# Can't remove "maps.apps.goo.gl" suggestion from address bar suggestion

Tags: google-chrome, search

Every time I type `maps.` I expect to receive the suggestion `maps.google.com`, which I can either follow or I can push tab and enter my search term. However, this suggestion is always at the top:

[image]

If I press tab, I can enter a location (e.g. "New York") and when pressing enter, it redirects me to
`https://www.google.com/maps/search/New%20York?hl=en&source=opensearch`,

so that's fine. But when pressing enter without entering a search term, I get this:

[image]

In the past, there was just a single link `maps.google.com` that either sent me to `maps.google.com` (when pressing enter) or allowed me to press tab and enter a search term. Now I have two suggestions, only one which works with tab-search, and the other that does both. How do I get rid of this suggestion?

Things I tried:

- `shift-delete`
- searching my history (turned up nothing)
- searching my bookmarks (turned up nothing)
- looked in my extensions (not sure what to look for, didn't seem to find any similar icons)

How do I again get a single `maps.google.com` suggestion that works both ways?

Answer (score 0):

Clearing my local browsing data resolved this issue. I signed out, removed browsing history and signed in again.